# $(...).data(...).split is not a function - JQuery

Tags: jquery

```js
var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

        $filterCheckboxes.on('change', function() {
        
        
          var selectedFilters = {};
        
          $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {
        
            if (!selectedFilters.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) {
              selectedFilters[this.name] = [];
            }
        
            selectedFilters[this.name].push(this.value);
        
          });
        
          // create a collection containing all of the filterable elements
          var $filteredResults = $('.speaker');
        
          // loop over the selected filter name -> (array) values pairs
          $.each(selectedFilters, function(name, filterValues) {
        
            // filter each .flower element
            $filteredResults = $filteredResults.filter(function() {
        
              var matched = false,
                currentFilterValues = $(this).data('category').split(' ');
                
                console.log( $(this).data('category'));
              // loop over each category value in the current .flower's data-category
              $.each(currentFilterValues, function(_, currentFilterValue) {
        
                // if the current category exists in the selected filters array
                // set matched to true, and stop looping. as we're ORing in each
                // set of filters, we only need to match once
        
                if ($.inArray(currentFilterValue, filterValues) != -1) {
                  matched = true;
                  return false;
                }
              });
        
              // if matched is true the current .flower element is returned
              return matched;
        
            });
          });
        
          $('.speaker').hide().filter($filteredResults).show();
        
        });
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="filters" name="fl-name" id="1" value="1">1

<input type="checkbox" class="filters" name="fl-name" id="2" value="2">2

<input type="checkbox" class="filters" name="fl-name" id="3" value="3">3




<div class="speaker" data-id="speaker1" data-category="1 2 3 4 5 6 8">Sample1</div>
 
 <div class="speaker" data-id="speaker2" data-category="2" style="">Sample2</div>
                          
                          
<div class="speaker" data-id="speaker3" data-category="2 5" style="">Sample 3</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

When i tried to filter data by checkbox it showing, please help...

.................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Thanks.

Comment: Please check what value do you get with `$(this).data('category')`. It might be `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: no bro... it's getting values..

Comment: So what value? Is it `object` or `string`? Can you share value in question?

Comment: when i entried to console `$(this).data('category')` i'm getting only this thing '1 2 3 4 5 6 8' and the error also...

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).data(...).split is not a function
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (speakers:2411)
    at jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
    at Function.grep (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at j (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.filter (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Array.<anonymous> (speakers:2408)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (speakers:2405)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)`

Comment: updated my question.... please see...

Comment: You're trying to console.log the value *after* it has already thrown the error. So you're seeing the *previous* loop iteration's value. Switch them around so that the console.log call is before the .split() line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like `$(this).data('category').toString().split(' ')`. The reason you were getting error was for second div it was returning only `2` and code was converting value to `number` `2`. Thus it was throwing error.

**P.S.** you can always put a `debugger` and check values at run time which will help you to find error.

You can check below.

```js
var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]');

$filterCheckboxes.on('change', function() {
  var selectedFilters = {};

  $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {
    if (!selectedFilters.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) {
      selectedFilters[this.name] = [];
    }
    selectedFilters[this.name].push(this.value);
  });

  // create a collection containing all of the filterable elements
  var $filteredResults = $('.speaker');

  // loop over the selected filter name -> (array) values pairs
  $.each(selectedFilters, function(name, filterValues) {

    // filter each .flower element
    $filteredResults = $filteredResults.filter(function() {
    
      var matched = false,
        currentFilterValues = $(this).data('category').toString().split(' ');


      // loop over each category value in the current .flower's data-category
      $.each(currentFilterValues, function(_, currentFilterValue) {

        // if the current category exists in the selected filters array
        // set matched to true, and stop looping. as we're ORing in each
        // set of filters, we only need to match once

        if ($.inArray(currentFilterValue, filterValues) != -1) {
          matched = true;
          return false;
        }
      });

      // if matched is true the current .flower element is returned
      return matched;

    });
  });

  $('.speaker').hide().filter($filteredResults).show();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="filters" name="fl-name" id="1" value="1">1
<input type="checkbox" class="filters" name="fl-name" id="2" value="2">2
<input type="checkbox" class="filters" name="fl-name" id="3" value="3">3
<div class="speaker" data-id="speaker1" data-category="1 2 3 4 5 6 8">Sample1</div>
<div class="speaker" data-id="speaker2" data-category="2" style="">Sample2</div>
<div class="speaker" data-id="speaker3" data-category="2 5" style="">Sample 3</div>
```

Comment: +1 for the note about adding a `debugger` statement and then looking at the variable values in the JavaScript debugger. So many of the questions posted on SO are things that could be solved using a debugger. I hope OP takes this advice to heart and gets familiar with the browser's developer tools. [Here's a starter for the Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools).

Comment: Glad to help! Drop a note here if you run into any questions about the DevTools and I will be happy to assist.